# mongo scala driver get _id after use insertOne

Tags: mongodb, scala, objectid

I hope get the document `ObjectId` which insert just now on use `insertOne`.
With my consider, a way is generate _id at client side, another way is query by a specify field with the document. Which method is better or have others?
ps: I'm know ObjectId in mongo generate with machine and time information.
In a word, I just wonder the saying of mongo ObjectId should generate on client or mongod server does means?

Answer (score 0):

As the MongoDB doc specifies, if you use the Mutable Document, you should get back the Document with the _id created by MongoDB automatically if you haven't provide one.

[Insert MongoDB -> See warning part](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-scala-driver/1.1/getting-started/quick-tour/#insert-a-document)

As you know in Scala the most part of the time we are working with inmutable objects by default. This is a good because you avoid the failures derived by the side effects.

For example, if you concatenate two lists, you will obtain a new List, and the same happens for a Map when you insert a key, a new Map is returned. As opossite in other languages as Java, you will have only one object (a pointer) that would change its internal state.

So if you use the inmmutable document of Mongo:

```
val doc: org.mongodb.scala.bson.collection.immutable.Document = Document("name" -> "MongoDB", "type" -> "database",
                             "count" -> 1, "info" -> Document("x" -> 203, "y" -> 102))

collection.insertOne(doc)...
```

"doc" would be inmmutable (so you don't will have the _id autogenerated by Mongo).

But if you use:

```
val doc: org.mongodb.scala.bson.collection.mutable.Document = Document("name" -> "MongoDB", "type" -> "database",
                             "count" -> 1, "info" -> Document("x" -> 203, "y" -> 102))

collection.insertOne(doc)...
```

After the insertion, you will have the _id field in your "doc" Document.

Other way as you said is to provide always an ObjectId using something like:

```
val doc: Document = Document("_id" -> ObjectId(), "name" -> "MongoDB"...)
```

Comment: How to use mutable.Document with insertOne method?

Comment: Take care that insertion is async in the new driver, so you have to subscribe to the Observable, or convert it to a Future and proccess it...

Comment: why collection.insertOne() method not consume a mutable document as parameter in scala driver 1.1.1?